# Custom Command Set is not saving

Tags: keyboard-shortcut

I'm trying to save a keyboard shortcut to my Custom Command Set in Final Cut Pro (FCP v10.4.7 on Mojave 10.14.6). I can get it to work for the duration of my session in Final Cut Pro but when I exit and re-open the app, that particular shortcut no longer works and I have to enter the Command Editor again to re-create it. Here are the specifics:

Desired effect: "Zoom Out" (in the Timeline)

Desired shortcut to use: CTRL + ALT + left arrow

Default command to be replaced: "Previous Pick"

(all other keyboard command edits I make for that Command Set seem to keep and work just fine)

One thing to note is that for it to be effective in the first place, I have to delete a Default command in FCP (the "Previous Pick" command) for the same key combo and replace it with my own. It won't work by just creating a new shortcut for that command (for which FCP will usually provide a warning message that the new command is replacing an established one and ask for permission to proceed in doing so... that doesn't happen in this particular case and I don't know why).

What I've tried so far:

- I have confirmed that the correct Custom Command Set is being selected in the Command Editor when the app starts up. My Custom Command set is called "Yahenda 1" and when I start the app, that is the Command Set selected in the Command Editor.
- I have tried selecting the "Default" Command Set and then re-selecting "Yahenda 1" but that has no effect on the problem.
- I have tried deleting the FCP Preferences (by closing the app, holding Command + Option while clicking the app icon and then following the Delete Preferences prompt) but that has not solved the problem.
- I have tried making the change in Command Editor and exporting to an entirely NEW Command Set and then closing and re-opening the app, but the problem persists.
- I have confirmed that 'CTRL + ALT + left arrow' is not a system reserved keyboard shortcut for Apple.

Can anyone help me figure out why this particular keyboard shortcut is not sticking across closing and re-opening of Final Cut Pro?